# First letters of XML attributes not colored correctly if capitalized

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, xml

If the first character(s) of an XML attribute are capitalized, they don't get colored in the usual attribute way:

```
<element InitialCap="1" initialLower="2" ALLCAPS="3" SOMEcaps="4" />
```

It would be nice to have the entire attribute name consistently colored.

Comment: Damn you Google!!!11

Answer (score 3):

[Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) bug, so they have to fix it.

I deployed the latest Prettify, see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like you need a status-3rd-party-bug tag.

Comment: More precisely http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list  to open the issue there.

Comment: @Jon B, that'd be `status-deferred` I think.

Answer (score 2):

Ack.  I thought that was fixed in http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/diff?spec=svn82&r=82&format=side&path=/trunk/src/prettify.js but apparently I needed to add an i to the next line too.

Submitted a fix at revision 86: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?r=86